# Can any eigenvalue have multiple eigenvectors if there is degeneracy in the spectrum?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I understand that if an n-dimensional matrix has n eigenvalues, each eigenvalue must correspond to one eigenvector.

When there is multiplicity in the roots of the characteristic polynomial of a matrix, the repeated eigenvalue can have as many eigenvectors as its multiplicity

Is there any limitation requiring the repeated eigenvalue in particular to take multiple eigenvectors?

In other words, can any eigenvalue take multiple eigenvectors in this situation?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, only the repeated one(s). For instance, the diagonal matrix with diagonal entries $3,3,3,2,2,1$ has a $3$-dimensional eigenspace for the eigenvalue $3$, a $2$-dimensional eigenspace for the eigenvalue $2$ and a $1$-dimensional eigenspace for the eigenvalue $1$. The dimension of the eigenspace corresponding to an eigenvalue (which is called its [geometric multiplicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors#Eigenspaces,_geometric_multiplicity,_and_the_eigenbasis_for_matrices)) is at most the multiplicity of the eigenvalue as a root of the characteristic polynomial (which is called its [algebraic multiplicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors#Algebraic_multiplicity)).